# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 1

Tags: java, jenkins, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Getting Serialization Exception only while building the code through jenkins pipeline. We will be creating the docker image through gradle distDocker and same will be deployed in kubernetes. The strange thing, the same code will works fine when we are creating the image by building the project through locally installed gradle. Both the gradle versions in jenkins and local are same.

Detailed exception :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 1
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:230)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:256)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:486)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:479)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:177)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:256)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:235)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:107)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you share the gradle.build file? How do you run and test this locally? Is it in an IDE or executing the jar file? I don't have a clear idea on this but the problem might be in necessary classes not getting bundled with the jar.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong text. `Unexpected character ('<'` means the server returned a non-JSON response, and so the client is failing. You may want to look at the server logs for more information

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa both in local and jenkins we are building using gradle wrapper. In local i am running the command from the terminal and not from the IDE.